# Are there any string methods, that will let me convert a string of numbers, to string of numbers and letters?

Tags: javascript, string

### Are there any string methods, that will let me convert a string of numbers, to string of numbers and letters?

I am trying to create a page with a button. Once the button has been clicked it will change the background color of the body element. However, no matter how random the number is generated It doesn't introduce letters **a-f** or **A-F** into the string. Are there any string methods that may help? [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yTnmG/).

JavaScript

---

```
(function(){ 
    var body;
    var button;

    body = document.querySelector('body');
    button = document.querySelector('span');

    function changeColor() {
        body.style.background = "#" + String(Math.random()).substring(2, 8);    
    }

    button.onclick = changeColor;
})();
```

Comment: No, but there's a Number method that will let you convert a number into a hex string!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toString(16)` would create a color hex, this is the most commonly used code for random colors

```
body.style.background = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eB5VG/)

Comment: why Math.random()* 16777215?

Comment: @frosty - There are 16,777,216 hex colors, starting with 000000 going up to FFFFFF

Comment: You will need to pad with zeroes, or this will not work.

Comment: Btw, if there are 16777216 colors you are generating one too few - you never reach white.

Comment: What about refactoring your code to make it shorter. I made this answer based on your solution: var color = "#" + Math.random().toString(16).substring(2, 8); Would it still give me the same randomness of colors?

Comment: @frosty: Only until you hit `0`, which would yield the empty string.

Comment: I think I saw if [**here**](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/) first, and it seems to be in fairly wide use now, but there are some issues in the comments, with solutions.